# How to renew Distribution Certificate in iOS?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have multiple applications in my Appstore, now my distribution certificate is going to expire within 3 days. How can I renew the same? Do I need to create new certificate or do we have any option to renew the same?

Answer (score 0):

If the distribution certificate get expired that's not going to affect your already publish apps on the App Store.

And possible you can not renew the certificate all you need to do is revoke the certificate and then create a new one. And all the App Store submission will be done using this new certificate.

Comment: Suppose if I revoke the certificate and create a new one, do I need to change anything for push notification certificate?

Or is it affect any of the other services?